user password denied in chrome ssh extenshion when connecting
In my quest to connect my home PC to the school smart board, I started trying to host my PC via SSH but I'm a beginner, so I started to experiment with my PC first:

I am running Debian Bookworm, installed OpenSSH via sudo apt -y install ssh, then
changed the SSH port to 1947 for fun 
When trying to connect to my computer from the SSH Chrome extension, it asks for the user password, but shows permission denied after giving it (the user is the main (and only) root user):  
I tried it from my terminal and it seems to work:  
I even tried connected from Android and it was working


While not addressing the issue, two things that stuck out were root should never be the SSH user on a non-single user OS (e.g. essentially embedded systems and routers only) and it's unwise to SSH via the user passphrase - instead, use an SSH key and encrypt the key with a passphrase (keys are inherently more secure and encrypting the key with a strong passphrase not only adds a double layer of protection, it allows the key to be kept on devices like smartphones without the risk of it being compromised; a key can also be kept on a hardware key, like a YubiKey - I prefer using a GPG key)

The remote username is “ssh mandal”? That doesn’t seem right. In fact I know your username is “ssh mandal” despite your first screenshot suggesting that’s what you’re attempting to use while the second screenshot shows the username is simply “mandal”. A user other than root cannot be root, it can be in the sudo group, but even that’s not identical to root.

Huh? My username is just "mandal" not "ssh mandal". how do I approach this?

I see. That's how it was. I typed "ssh" twice because the Chrome extension said to type "ssh" and then press "tab," and then type any command.
